# Issue with convering from Silverlight HashTable to IDictionary

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, collections, dictionary

I am currently updating some exising Silverlight code and moving helper classes into a Silverlight 5 library but I am struggling with the change from a HashTable implementation to a IDictionary implementation as shown below.

This functionality allows the enumerations to be attributed allowing the looking up of a string value.

The code compiles but fails on the `stringValues.Add(value, attrs[0]);` line in the `ParseEnumStrings` class with the below exception details.

Any idea what I have done wrong in the conversion of the code?

**Exception**

```
The value "Today" is not of type "System.Type" and cannot be used in this generic collection.
Parameter name: key.

   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowWrongKeyTypeArgumentException(Object key, Type targetType)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.System.Collections.IDictionary.Add(Object key, Object value)
   at Silverlight.Helper.Enums.ParseEnumStrings.GetStringValue(Enum value) in Z:\Perforce\Development\Microsoft .Net\dotNet 4.0\Silverlight 5\Helper\Helper\Enums\ParseEnumStrings.cs:line 25
   at QSmartFaultsByZone.Web.Models.QSmartService.GetRTF(Int32 buID, String zones, ReportTimePeriod time) in Z:\Perforce\Development\Microsoft .Net\dotNet 4.0\Silverlight 5\QSmart Faults By Zone\QSmartFaultsByZone.Web\Models\QSmartService.cs:line 114
   at GetRTF(DomainService , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.ReflectionDomainServiceDescriptionProvider.ReflectionDomainOperationEntry.Invoke(DomainService domainService, Object[] parameters)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.DomainOperationEntry.Invoke(DomainService domainService, Object[] parameters, Int32& totalCount)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.DomainService.Query(QueryDescription queryDescription, IEnumerable`1& validationErrors, Int32& totalCount)
```

**Enum**

```
public enum ReportTimePeriod 
{
    [StringValue("Today")]
    Today = 0,
    [StringValue("Twenty Four Hours")]
    TwentyFourHours = 1,
    [StringValue("Week")]
    Week = 2,
    [StringValue("Month")]
    Month = 3
}
```

**String Value Attribute**

```
public class StringValueAttribute : Attribute
{
    private readonly string value;

    public StringValueAttribute(string value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public string Value
    {
        get { return this.value; }
    }
}
```

**Legacy HashTable class**

```
public class ParseEnumStrings
{
    private static Hashtable _stringValues = new Hashtable();

    public static string GetStringValue(Enum value)
    {
        string output = null;
        Type type = value.GetType();

        //Check first in our cached results...
        if (_stringValues.ContainsKey(value))
            output = (_stringValues[value] as StringValueAttribute).Value;
        else
        {
            //Look for our 'StringValueAttribute' 
            //in the field's custom attributes
            FieldInfo fi = type.GetField(value.ToString());
            StringValueAttribute[] attrs =fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(StringValueAttribute),false) as StringValueAttribute[];
            if (attrs.Length > 0)
            {
                _stringValues.Add(value, attrs[0]);
                output = attrs[0].Value;
            }
        }

        return output;
    }
```

**New IDictionary implementation**

```
public class ParseEnumStrings
{
    private static IDictionary stringValues = new Dictionary<Type, StringValueAttribute>();

    public static string GetStringValue(Enum value)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        Type type = value.GetType();

        if (stringValues.Contains(value))
            result=(stringValues[value] as StringValueAttribute).Value;
        else
        {
            FieldInfo f = type.GetField(value.ToString());
            StringValueAttribute[] attrs = f.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(StringValueAttribute), false) as StringValueAttribute[];
            if (attrs.Length > 0)
            {
                stringValues.Add(value, attrs[0]);
                result = attrs[0].Value;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

**Implementation**

```
return (from rft in qs.spBusinessProductsRFTTodayV2(zones, buID, ParseEnumStrings.GetStringValue(time))
        select new RightFirstTimeReportDto
        {
            Builds=rft.Builds,
            BuildsWithFaults=rft.BuildsWithFaults,
            Name=rft.Name,
            RightFirstTime=rft.RFT,
            ZoneID=rft.ZoneID
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: The problem is, your dictionary's `TKey` is `System.Type`, but you're expecting to use the values of your enumeration as keys. The dictionary's type should probably be IDictionary<object, StringValueAttribute>

Comment: That fixed the add problem but highlighted another. Does the contains method on the IDictionary work in the same way as the HashTable? Its not finding existing items.

Comment: Notice how you're using `ContainsKey` in the original, but `Contains` in the new version.

Comment: Figured it out. Please put your comment as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, your dictionary's `TKey` is `System.Type`, but you're expecting to use the values of your enumeration as keys. The dictionary's type should probably be `IDictionary<object, StringValueAttribute>`

(Also, you're using `Contains` instead of `ContainsKey` in the second version. Although the documentation does state that `IDictionary.Contains` should look at the keys, so I'm not entirely sure why that doesn't do what you expect.)

Comment: The reason it was not working as expected is that the method was being called asynchronously a number of times so the initial 'Contains' check might not always catch the problem. I have changed the method to allow for this and it works. Thanks

Comment: Oh, in that case I suggest you wrap the whole thing inside a `lock(stringValues) { }`. Or perhaps the "allow for this" was exactly that?

Comment: Thats exactly what I did. Thanks again